# react table sort a column by another column

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I am trying to sort my table data by hidden column, for example if I click on data_1, I want it to be sorted by my hidden column data_2, is it possible?

```
toggleSortBy: Function(descending, multi) => void
```

this function maybe works but i dont know how it works

Comment: could you please provide an example and a full description please?
sorry, I couldn't understand what you said

Comment: @JabalLogian for example:

`column: {
                    Header: "Name",
                    accessor: "name",
                },{
                    Header: "id",
                    accessor: "id",
                    isVisible:false
                },
`

if i click the column 'Name' i want that column sorted by id that is hidden

Answer (score 0):

`sortType` as a functiona can be helpful in solving above problem, details of it can be found at - https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useSortBy#column-options

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to dig out a solution for this,  here is my workaround, but I am still looking for a method for Not overwriting the onclick callback function.

1. Add **toggleSortBy** property in useTable Hook(will use later)

   ```
        const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow, toggleSortBy } =
    useTable({ columns, data, initialState }, useSortBy);
   ```
2. Overwrite onclick property in **useSortBy** Hook

   ```
                 <th
                  {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}
                  onClick={(e) => {
                    e.persist();
                    if (column.id === 'name') {
                      toggleSortBy('id', false, false);
                      return;
                    }
                    column.toggleSortBy(undefined, false);
                  }}
   ```

[Here is source code of useSortBy](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/master/src/plugin-hooks/useSortBy.js)

You can also tryout several example here: [enter link description here](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples)